# Help making a multiple choice quiz with jFormer (jQuery and PHP)

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with a multiple choice quiz I'm making with [jFormer](http://www.jformer.com/).

Basically I'm really new to PHP and I'm having trouble with the following:

- Finding out how to arrange radio buttons vertically (at the moment I'm basing my quiz on the 'Survey' Demo (http://www.jformer.com/demos/survey/) and it won't let me rearrange the radio buttons. Instead, when I do, it treats each radio button separately and you can only pick the first one.
- All my radio buttons are labeled A - E (e.g. `< input id="statement1-choice3" type="radio" value="C" name="statement1" / >`) How do I then calculate the outcome so that those who picked a majority of A answers get shown a different div to those who picked a majority of B answers?

Thanks in advance,

Ella

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the outcome, you'll probably have all the answers in a list (array).

In your case the array variable would be `$_POST` I think...

So when you have an array with answers:

```
$data = array(
    'question1' => 'a',
    'question2' => 'b',
    'question3' => 'a',
    'question4' => 'c',
    'question5' => 'a',
    'question6' => 'e',
    'question7' => 'c',
    'question8' => 'd',
    'question9' => 'a',
    'question10' => 'a',
    'question11' => 'b'
);
```

You can go through each answer of the array and look which answer there has been given.
Then count each answer and look of which are the most.

```
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$c = 0;
$d = 0;
$e = 0;

foreach($data as $question => $answer) {
    if($answer == 'a') {
        $a++;
    } else if($answer == 'b') {
        $b++;
    } else if($answer == 'c') {
        $c++;
    } else if($answer == 'd') {
        $d++;
    } else if($answer == 'e') {
        $e++;
    }
}

if($a > $b && $a > $c && $a > $d && $a > e) {
    echo '<div>Most of your answers where A</div>';
} else if($b > $c && $b > $d && $b > $e) {
    echo '<div>Most of your answers where B</div>';
} else if($c > $d && $c > $e) {
    echo '<div>Most of your answers where C</div>';
} else if($d > $e) {
    echo '<div>Most of your answers where D</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div>Most of your answers where E</div>';
}
```

Since your still beginning with PHP I'd make the code so clear as possible.
There are many (more difficult and not easy understandable) ways to do this.